# SQLite to Register on multiple device- Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm developing a course selection app for a university. Students must register to application. I'm using SQLlite by using db helper, my table contains studentID,password,name etc.

My question is this sqlite db stays on only local ? I mean, how can i reach student table on multiple device, read and write at the same time. When it puts on the play store thousand of student will use it.

Which technologies should i use, where should i put the db ?
I'm really confused about it, thanks for advance.

Comment: Yes SQLite is local database. If you want a common database for all users, use mysql database for example.

Comment: that is not possible that SQLite is access in other device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `sqlite` it is not possible. You have to create the database on `server`. For that thing you can use `mysql`, `oracle` etc. So from server `n` number of students can access the data.

There are many times when your Android app will need to fetch data from the internet, to provide users with fresh information and/or data. There are different ways your app could achieve this. You could set up your own `web` `service/API`, or you could be fetching from an already existing `service/API`.

`1)` To get the data from `API` Luckily, there is a class just for this, called `AsyncTask`. From the `Android documentation`, AsyncTask facilitates the proper and easy use of the `UI thread`, by allowing the performance of background operations, and publishing the results on the UI thread without the need for manipulating threads and handlers. In simple words, `AsyncTask` handles all the complexity for you.

`2)` To make use of the `AsyncTask` features, you must subclass it, and provide 3 generic types, called `Params`, `Progress` and `Result`. Params refers to the parameters that would be parsed to your Task, `Progress` refers to the progress indicator/counter type, and Result is what would be returned on completion of the task. AsyncTask has 4 important methods, `onPreExecute` (what to do before the expensive task begins), `doInBackground` (the actual expensive operation goes in here), `onProgressUpdate` (what to do to show progress), and `onPostExecute` (what to do when the task is complete).

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            String email = emailText.getText().toString();
            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + "email=" + email + "&apiKey=" + API_KEY);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
        }
    }
```

`Read` this tutorial to use this feature: http://www.androidauthority.com/use-remote-web-api-within-android-app-617869/

Also see this documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html